# Firebase query between dates

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have to query some data from firebase. The idea is filtering between dates. So I want to get an event if is active. I want to do all in server, And I don't know if it possible. I've created a field which contains the startDate and endDate, something like 20180101-20181231 the eight first characters are the startDate and the last characters are the endDate. Now if I want to get the events which are actives today (20181030) I would like to query something like `startAt(20180101-20181031).endAt(20181030-20181231)`, but I've realized that it won't work. Because I don't have the start and the end date of the event, and if for example today were on 2017 the start date would be later than endDate. I've tried with `startAt(00000000-20181030) endAt(20181030-00000000)`, but it only works with the startDate....

The question is if it is possible in firebase in server side to get the active events or I have to filter in client side.

Comment: If you store your dates as UNIX time I think it could be a solution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time You will however have to handle the logic from converting UNIX time to date/time and vice versa :)

Comment: @AlchemistShahed I'm sorry but I don't understand you :( I'm not sure if using this I could query between dates in server side.